# How to write a cobol code to do the below logic?

Tags: cobol

1) Read a line of 2000 characters and replace all SPACES with a single "+" plus character. i.e. Convert `"A    B"` to `"A+B"` or `"A B"` to `"A+B"`

2)Read a line of 2000 characters, then search for a specific patterns like "PWD" or "INI" or etc and finally store next 6 characters into a variable.

3) Read a line of 2000 characters and store the last word in the string to a variable.

Edit:
I use Micro Focus COBOL.

[This](http://s32.postimg.org/7aqcy3jlx/IMG_20160614_190250_01.jpg) is a screenshot of my piece of code so far.

My code is below. It removes a few spaces but not all. Try writing any sentence with random numbers of spaces in between words in and input file for test-data.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. SALAUT.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
    FILE-CONTROL.
     SELECT IN-FILE ASSIGN TO "INFILE"
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL
            FILE STATUS IS WS-IN-FILE-STATUS.
     SELECT OUT-FILE ASSIGN TO "OUTFILE"
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL
            FILE STATUS IS WS-OUT-FILE-STATUS.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD IN-FILE.
   01 FS-IN-FILE                           PIC X(200).
   FD OUT-FILE.
   01 FS-OUT-FILE                          PIC X(200).
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 WS-ATMA-C.
         03 WS-OUT-FILE-STATUS       PIC X(02).
         03 WS-IN-FILE-STATUS        PIC X(02).
         03 WS-LOOP-COUNTER          PIC 9(03) VALUE 1.
         03 WS-IN-EOF                PIC X value 'N'.
         03 WS-IN-FILE-LEN           PIC 9(03).
         03 WS-IN-SPACE-CNT          PIC 9(03) VALUE 1. 
         03 FS-IN-FILE-2             PIC X(200).
         03 WS-TRIL-SPACE-CNT        PIC 9(03).
         03 WS-TOT-SPACE-CNT         PIC 9(03). 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PARA.     
        OPEN INPUT IN-FILE.
        IF WS-IN-FILE-STATUS <> '00'
         EXHIBIT 'IN-FILE-OPEN-ERROR : STOP-RUN'
         EXHIBIT NAMED WS-IN-FILE-STATUS
         PERFORM MAIN-PARA-EXIT
        END-IF.
        OPEN OUTPUT OUT-FILE.
        IF WS-OUT-FILE-STATUS <> '00'
         EXHIBIT 'OUT-FILE-OPEN-ERROR : STOP-RUN'
         EXHIBIT NAMED WS-OUT-FILE-STATUS
         PERFORM MAIN-PARA-EXIT
        END-IF.

        PERFORM SPACE-REMOVER-PARA THRU SPACE-REMOVER-PARA-EXIT.

         CLOSE IN-FILE.
         IF WS-IN-FILE-STATUS <> '00'
          EXHIBIT 'IN-FILE-CLOSE-ERROR : STOP-RUN'
          EXHIBIT NAMED WS-IN-FILE-STATUS
          PERFORM MAIN-PARA-EXIT
         END-IF.
        CLOSE OUT-FILE.
        IF WS-OUT-FILE-STATUS <> '00'
         EXHIBIT 'IN-FILE-CLOSE-ERROR : STOP-RUN'
         EXHIBIT NAMED WS-OUT-FILE-STATUS
         PERFORM MAIN-PARA-EXIT
        END-IF.
   MAIN-PARA-EXIT.
      STOP RUN.
   SPACE-REMOVER-PARA.
    PERFORM UNTIL WS-IN-EOF = 'Y'
    INITIALIZE FS-IN-FILE FS-OUT-FILE WS-IN-FILE-LEN FS-IN-FILE-2
    READ IN-FILE 
     AT END 
      MOVE 'Y' TO WS-IN-EOF 
     NOT AT END
      INSPECT FS-IN-FILE TALLYING WS-IN-FILE-LEN FOR CHARACTERS
      EXHIBIT NAMED WS-IN-FILE-LEN
      MOVE 1 TO WS-LOOP-COUNTER
      IF WS-IN-FILE-LEN <> 0
       PERFORM UNTIL WS-IN-SPACE-CNT <= ZEROS 
       INSPECT FS-IN-FILE TALLYING WS-TOT-SPACE-CNT FOR ALL "  "
       INSPECT FUNCTION REVERSE (FS-IN-FILE) TALLYING 
                    WS-TRIL-SPACE-CNT FOR LEADING "  "
       INITIALIZE WS-IN-SPACE-CNT
       COMPUTE WS-IN-SPACE-CNT = 
                    WS-TOT-SPACE-CNT - WS-TRIL-SPACE-CNT
       PERFORM VARYING WS-LOOP-COUNTER FROM 1 BY 1
          UNTIL WS-LOOP-COUNTER >=
                WS-IN-FILE-LEN - (2 * WS-TRIL-SPACE-CNT) 
        IF FS-IN-FILE(WS-LOOP-COUNTER:2) = "  "
         STRING FS-IN-FILE(1:WS-LOOP-COUNTER - 1) DELIMITED BY SIZE
                FS-IN-FILE(WS-LOOP-COUNTER + 2
                           : WS-IN-FILE-LEN - WS-LOOP-COUNTER - 2)
                                              DELIMITED BY SIZE
                INTO FS-IN-FILE-2
         END-STRING
         INITIALIZE FS-IN-FILE 
         MOVE FS-IN-FILE-2 TO FS-IN-FILE
         INITIALIZE FS-IN-FILE-2
        END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       INITIALIZE WS-LOOP-COUNTER WS-TRIL-SPACE-CNT WS-TOT-SPACE-CNT
       END-PERFORM
       WRITE FS-OUT-FILE FROM FS-IN-FILE
       IF WS-OUT-FILE-STATUS <> '00'
        EXHIBIT 'OUT-FILE-WRITE-ERROR : STOP-RUN'
        EXHIBIT NAMED WS-OUT-FILE-STATUS
        PERFORM MAIN-PARA-EXIT
       END-IF
      END-IF
    END-READ
    END-PERFORM.
   SPACE-REMOVER-PARA-EXIT.
        EXIT.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.com. Is this homework? What did you try yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thank you Marti. Its something where i want to automate a piece of my job. Secondly i tried INSPECT to remove 2 consecutive spaces by a single space, but idk how to stop the loop as in each next line their their will be random number of spaces. Third i dont know how to get the column position of a word in a string in cobol. Once i can extract the column position of words like "PWD" or "INT" than it would be easier to extract other necessary data from the read line of length 2000.

Comment: So what are you wanting to do if a line has 200 spaces consecutively? Would you then want 200 '+' signs consecutively?
Do you have an example of your attempted code?

Comment: Sorry i dont have my piece of code. If there are 200 spaces consecutive spaces then i want to replace it with a single "+"  character. And a important point to note is that not each line will have same number of spaces consecutively. Thanks Thraydor

Comment: @S.K.S. So you want a loop to remove multiple spaces, a loop to change any spaces left to a '+', then you want to check for key words and get the following information, then you want to store the last word in a variable?
Are these all on the same line of 2000 characters?
What have you got figured out for your loops so far?

Comment: All three of these are alternate option for me for to get a lead with my approach. Any one of them will do good. At times i might go for all three approaches on a single line depending upon other conditions. For removing spaces i can use INSPECT.. REPLACING keywords and replace 2 consecutive spaces to 1 space and repeate it till all consecutive spaces are replaced by single space and then finally with a character "+". For this i need to have a loop as the number of spaces are not same every time.

Comment: @S.K.S. You might have a look at delimiting by spaces into a cobol table, then you could string it back together with '+' as filler. Without having more of an idea of what you're truly expecting or what you've tried, it is difficult to help.

Comment: Thanks thraydor. But delimited was only when I know the exact number of words coming in the next string. Second opinion of finding column position of a pattern in a random string of 2000 characters can do it all in a single shot, but i don't see any way of getting offset(from 1st character of the string) of a patter in cobol. Is there a way to trip excess spaces on either side of a string?

Comment: Which COBOL? @S.K.S.  FUNCTION TRIM(field LEADING/TRAILING/no-keyword-means-both) will trim spaces.  GnuCOBOL has an extension intrinsic SUBSTITUTE that can replace with different length strings for pattern and replacement.  Otherwise, for more sophisticated parsing operations you'd likely be best off with a character by character loop and a small state machine feeding into a STRING operations WITH POINTER to build up the destination field.

Comment: What about trailing spaces? You realise you can't "get rid" of those from a fixed-length field. To get the last "word", start from the "back" of the field, and loop until you find the first non-space (or non-+) and then continue to the previous (remember you are going backwards) space/+. Don't run off the front of the field when there is only one "word" present. For the PWD and INI, simplest is to use UNSTRING with PWD or INI as the delimiter, and a one-byte initial "receiving field" (called something like value-irrelevant) and a six-byte second receiving field.

Comment: Thanks... I will try all these ideas and try to put my code over here. Need some time for it.

Comment: If we knew which COBOL compiler you use and possibly what platform it will run on, we might be able to suggest a specific solution. The answers/comments so far should work on essentially all platforms with all compilers. But sometimes a platform-specific function can help. Windows? Unix? IBM mainframe or midrange?

Comment: From the Micro Focus: "As a compatibility issue, its recommended that you modify your source code to use actual DISPLAY statements, and that you not add new EXHIBIT statements to your COBOL program." `EXHIBIT` was not even supported in the later OS/VS COBOL releases, which is, what, 35 or more years ago? Please don't use it. Please paste your code into the question. An image is useless.

Comment: Sure i will add my code by this weekend for your reference. Meanwhile can you tell me what functional differences are there between microfocus cobol and mainframe cobol.

Comment: The Enterprise COBOL manuals are available for free from IBM, downloadable as PDFs or searchable in the KnowledgeCentre. If you have a specific version in mind, chose that one. If you are just wanting to know in general, pick V4.2.

Comment: Was 2000 in your original question a typo?

Comment: No its not a typo... I just reduced the string length for easy testing

Comment: I suggest to remove the down-votes as the question got a lot better.

Comment: @S.K.S. Does one of the the provided answers work for you? If yes: please mark it as answer, if no: please comment on the answer what you miss [or edit your question if you cannot comment because of reputation].

Comment: thank you all for your support. Let's close this topic as of now. Honestly i'm been busy with other business commitments, hence i cannot test this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `INSPECT REPLACING` only allows to replace the same number of bytes you can not use it. As Brian pointed out your COBOL runtime may comes with options like GnuCOBOL's `FUNCTION SUBSTITUTE`. In any case the question "Which COBOL" is still useful to be answered.

To do Thraydor's approach use `UNSTRING` to a table using a string pointer. Something along

```
MOVE 1 TO strpoint
PERFORM VARYING table-idx FROM 1 BY 1
        UNTIL   table-idx = table-max
   UNSTRING your2000line DELIMITED BY ALL SPACES
            INTO tmp-table (table-idx)
            WITH POINTER strpoint
        NOT ON OVERFLOW
            EXIT PERFORM
   END-UNSTRING
END-PERFORM
```

Another approach which always work is a simple `PERFORM` over the 2000 bytes with a bunch of `IF your2000line (pos:1)` statements (if possible: combine it to a single `EVALUATE`) checking byte by byte (comparing the last byte for removing the duplicate bytes) transferring the source with replacements to a temporary field and `MOVE` it back once you're finished

Please edit your question to show what exactly you've tried and you can get much better answers.

Comment: Thanks all for your time and help. Plz find below link to screenshot of my piece of code. I use microfocus cobol http://s32.postimg.org/7aqcy3jlx/IMG_20160614_190250_01.jpg

Comment: It seems that this question is answered then, isn't it?

Thank you for the screen shot, but even better would be to accept the answer and edit it afterwards (either keeping the original source or adding yours below).

Comment: I have tried the approach, but its not working. I want help from you guys to find out whats wrong.

Comment: Then I suggest to edit your question, adding your code (as text) below your current text and providing the information what actually "is not working". This leads to the question being in-line with the Stackoverflow rules and will lead to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, bear in mind that COBOL is a language of dialects. There are also active commercial compilers which target the 1974, 1985, 2002 (now obsolete, incorporated in 2014) and 2014 Standards. All with their own Language Extensions, which may or many not be honoured in a different COBOL compiler.

If you are targeting your learning to a particular environment (IBM Mainframe COBOL you have said) then use that dialect as a subset of what is available to you in the actual COBOL you are using. Which means using the IBM Manuals.

Don't pick and chose stuff from places and use it just because it somehow seemed like a good idea at the time.

I have to admit that EXHIBIT was great fun to use, but it was only ever a Language Extension, and IBM dropped it by at least the later releases of OS/VS COBOL. It, like ON, was a "debugging" statement, although that didn't prevent their being used "normally". There's additional overhead to using EXHIBIT over a simple DISPLAY. IBM Enterprise COBOL only has a simple DISPLAY.

Whilst you may think it fun to use pictograms (the "oh my goodness, what symbol should I use for this" of a figure attempting to pull his own hair out) be aware that that particular symbol was a latecomer to the 2014 Standard, and if it appears in Enterprise COBOL within the next 20 to 50 years I'd be surprised (very low of the list of things to do, another cute way to write "not equal to" when many *already* exist, and COBOL even has an ELSE).

Some pointers. Don't have a procedure called "remove-all-the-spaces" if what it does is itself is "everything-including-install-a-new-kitchen-sink". Is it any wonder you can't find why it doesn't work?

Many, many, many COBOL programs have the task of reading a file, until the end, and processing the records in the file. Get yourself one of those working well first. Is that relevant to the "business process" the program is addressing? No, it's just technical stuff, which you can't do without **so hide it somewhere**. Where? in PERFORMed procedures (paragraphs or SECTIONS). Don't expect someone who quickly wants to know what your program is doing to want to read the stuff which every program does. Hide it.

You can find quite a bit of general advice here about writing COBOL programs. Pay attention to those which advise of the use of full-stops/periods, priming reads, and the general structure of COBOL programs.

It is very important to describe things accurately. Work on good, descriptive, accurate names for data-names and procedures. A file is a collection of records.

You have cut down the size of your data to make testing easier, without realising that you have a problem with your data-definitions when you go back to full-length data. Your "counters" can only hold three digits, when they need to be able to cope with the numbers up to 2000.

There is no point in doing something to a piece of data, and then immediately squishing that something with something else which is not related in any way to the original something.

```
MOVE SPACE TO B
MOVE A TO B
```

The first MOVE is redundant, superflous, and does nothing but suck up CPU time and confuse the next reader of your program. "Is there some code missing, because otherwise that's just plain dumb".

This is a variant of that example with the MOVE, and you are doing this all over the place:

```
   INITIALIZE WS-IN-SPACE-CNT
   COMPUTE WS-IN-SPACE-CNT = 
                WS-TOT-SPACE-CNT - WS-TRIL-SPACE-CNT
```

The INITIALIZE is a waste of space, resources, and an introducer of confusion, and extra lines of code to make your program more difficult to understand.

Also, don't "reset" things after they are used, so that they are "ready for next time". That creates dependencies which a future amender of your program will not expect. Even when expected/noticed, they make the code harder to follow.

Exactly what is wrong with your code is impossible to say without knowing what you think is wrong with it. For instance, there is not even a sign of a "+" replacing any spaces, so if you feel that is what it wrong, you simply haven't coded for it.

You've also only attempted one of the three tasks. If once of those not working is what you think is wrong...

Knowing what you think is wrong is one thing, but there are a lot of other problems. If you sit down and sort those out, methodically, then you'll come up with a "structurally" COBOL program which you'll find its easier to understand what your own code does, and where problems lie.

```
A  B   C  D    E

A+B+C+D+E
```

To get from the first to the second using STRING, look into Simon's suggestion to use WITH POINTER.

Another approach you could take would be using reference-modification.

Either way, you'd be build your result field a piece at a time

```
This field intentionally blank
A
A+B
A+B+C
A+B+C+D
A+B+C+D+E
```

Rather than tossing all the data around each time. There are also other ways to code it, but that can be for later.